# Simple conditional statement not working (equal to) wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements

I have a simple conditional statement to check for a certain products parent category in woocommerce / wordpress but it's not working even though the values are true (to me). Any ideas?

```
function get_parent_terms($term) {
    if ($term->parent > 0) {
        $term = get_term_by("id", $term->parent, "product_cat");
        if ($term->parent > 0) {
            get_parent_terms($term);
        } else return $term;
    }
    else return $term;
}

# Will return all categories of a product, including parent categories
function all_cat_classes($post) {
    $cats = ""; 
    $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, "product_cat");
    $key = 0;

    // foreach product_cat get main top product_cat
    foreach ($terms as $cat) {
        $cat = get_parent_terms($cat);
        $cats .= (strpos($cats, $cat->slug) === false ? $cat->slug." " : "");
        $key++;
    }

    return $cats;
}
```

then this code ends up being false and echos out `nope: causes`

```
$damaincat = all_cat_classes($post);
if($damaincat == 'causes')  echo '<style>#text-3 { display: none !important; }</style>'; else echo 'nope: '.$damaincat;
```

I'm stumped =0(

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump(all_cat_classes($post));`?

Comment: You just solved it for me by asking me to do that. There was a space after the word "causes " string(7) "causes "

Comment: then you can use trim() such as `if(trim($damaincat) == 'causes')`

Comment: @ClintC.: There you go! Yes, as Akam suggested, you can use `trim()` to trim the whitespaces from the beginning and end of a string. :>